# Calculate File size on client

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I have 3 classes, Server, Client and TransferMain. I need to show on the client the percentage of the transfer that's complete, but how do i know the file length on the client if the file isn't there yet?

Keep in mind that the client and the Server run on different pc's.

code: https://pastebin.com/CBZauNRz

```
package servidor;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;



@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Servidor {
    private ServerSocket socketServidor;
    private Socket socketConexao;
    private int porta;

    public Servidor(int porta) {
        this.porta = porta;
    }
    public void iniciaConexaoServidor() {

        try {
            this.socketServidor = new ServerSocket(this.porta);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Não conseguiu iniciar o socket do servidor");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            this.socketConexao = socketServidor.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Não conseguiu aceitar a conexao com o cliente.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void enviarArquivo(String diretorio) throws Exception {
        File arquivo = new File(diretorio);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(arquivo);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        OutputStream os = this.socketConexao.getOutputStream();
        byte[] conteudo;
        long fileLength = arquivo.length();
        long current = 0;

        while(current!=fileLength){
            int size = 10000;
            if(fileLength - current >= size)
                current += size;    
            else{
                size = (int)(fileLength - current);
                current = fileLength;
            }
            conteudo = new byte[size];
            bis.read(conteudo, 0, size);
            os.write(conteudo);
            System.out.println("Mandando arquivo ... "+(current*100)/fileLength+"% completo!"+"ip do cliente:"+socketConexao.getInetAddress());
        }  

        os.flush();
        this.socketConexao.close();
        this.socketServidor.close();
        bis.close();
        System.out.println("Arquivo enviado com sucesso!");
    }
}
```

Client:

```
package Cliente;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Cliente {
    private Socket socketCliente;
    int porta;
    String address;
    public Cliente(int porta, String address) {
        this.porta=porta;
        this.address=address;
    }
    public void iniciarConexaoCliente() {
        try {
            this.socketCliente = new Socket(address, porta);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.out.println("Não conseguiu iniciar a conexao com o servidor");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Não conseguiu iniciar a conexao com o servidor");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void transferenciaArquivo(String diretorio) throws IOException {
        byte[] conteudo = new byte[10000];

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(diretorio);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        InputStream is = socketCliente.getInputStream();
        int bytesRead = 0;
        long current= 0;
        long conteudoLength = conteudo.length;
        while((bytesRead=is.read(conteudo))!=-1) {
            bos.write(conteudo, 0, bytesRead);
            current = bytesRead;
            System.out.println("Recebendo arquivo..."+(current*100)/conteudoLength+"% recebido!" +"ip do servidor:"+this.address);
        }
        bos.flush();
        socketCliente.close();

        System.out.println("Arquivo recebido!");
    }

}
```

TransferMain:

```
import Cliente.Cliente;
import servidor.Servidor;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class TransferMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String adress; //192.168.25.9
        int porta;
        String escolha;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner str = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Servidor ou cliente? S ou C");
        escolha = str.nextLine();
        System.out.println("endereço ip: ");
        adress = str.nextLine();
        System.out.println("porta: ");
        porta = in.nextInt();
        if(escolha.equals("S")) {
            Servidor servidor = new Servidor(porta);
            servidor.iniciaConexaoServidor();
            String diretorioServidor = "MusicasTeste.rar";
            try {
                servidor.enviarArquivo(diretorioServidor);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
             Cliente cliente = new Cliente(porta, adress);
             try {
                 cliente.iniciarConexaoCliente();
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 System.out.println("Não iniciou a conexão com o Cliente.");
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
             String diretorioCliente = "MusicasTeste2.rar";
             try {
                 cliente.transferenciaArquivo(diretorioCliente);
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 System.out.println("Não conseguiu receber o arquivo.");
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }

        }





    }

}
```

Comment: You could make it so that when the client requests the file, the server responds first with the length of the file, and then the data, so you know how much data to expect, and thus the percentage of the transfer

Comment: thats a good idea, i will try it